# Mounting EFS Volume in Non available region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

Is there any way to mount EFS volume to multiple instances in Mumbai Region. EFS service is currently not available in Mumbai region.Or is there any other service which i can use instead of EFS. I need to mount sigle disk space to multiple instance

Comment: Hi Sreeraju V, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If EFS is not available in your region you've got a couple of options:

- Set up your own **NFS server on a Linux instance** - not Highly Available but may be good enough for non-critical use
- Use **distributed cluster filesystem** like [GlusterFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluster#GlusterFS) or [CEPH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceph_(software)) - these will provide better resiliency and high availability at the expense of higher complexity.

Depends on your requirements.

Hope that helps :)